# Soft sheaves on $T_1$-space

Tags: proof-verification, sheaf-theory

Suppose we have a topological space $X$ and an open subset $U \subseteq X$ with inclusion $j \colon U \hookrightarrow X$. 
If we have a sheaf $\mathcal F \in \text{Sh}(X)$, then we know that in general the canonical sheaf morphism 
$$
\mathcal F \to j_*\mathcal F|_U
$$
is not surjective. It is, though, for *flasque* sheaves.

I was wondering if the surjectivity still holds if $\mathcal F$ is only **soft**, but $X$ is $T_1$, i.e. every single-point-set is closed. I think the answer is yes, because as $\{x\}$ is closed for every $x \in X$, the softness of $\mathcal F$ implies the surjectivity of the canonical map
$$
\mathcal F(X) \to \mathcal F_x
$$
which also implies the surjectivity of
$$
\mathcal F_x \to (j_*\mathcal F|_U)_x.
$$

Is this correct or am I missing something?
Thanks in advance for any help / comments!